# Doubt in lecture 1 of Allan adams' course on QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Did anyone understand the reason for why the results in the experiment white->hardness->color, and white->hardness->mirrors->color came different? what is the difference between the two experiments?

In the lecture adams describes two properties of electrons, which he names color and hardness, both being binary in nature, i.e. white/black, and soft/hard.
He claims these are alternate names for two conventionally well known properties of electrons, and shall be referred to via these names at the moment.

Moving ahead he describes an apparatus called a property box. A color box can tell the color of an electron, and a hardness box can tell the hardness of an electron. 
The principles involved here are that the properties are repetitive, i.e. once color turns out to be white it remains white, and same goes for hardness. However if you determine the hardness of a set of white electrons and then try figuring out their color, it turns out that the odds are 50/50 in favor of both white and black. Thus this experiment is indicative of the uncertainty principle.
Also these two properties are unrelated, i.e. a white electron can be any of the two: hard, soft.
Now he describes an apparatus wherein he uses white electrons, passes them through a hardness box, and then uses mirrors to aggregate all of those electrons into a single beam and then passes that single beam through a color box. The result herein is that all the electrons are white. He claims that mirrors cannot do any altercations except for redirecting of the electron path.
My question is that if mirrors are not changing anything, then why are the two experiments giving different results? According to me the apparatus is entirely identical. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please explain the entire setup, the video is an hour long.

Comment: Hi Ekdeep. You don't give a link to the video and you don't tell us the time in the video where the experiment is described. Without watching the entire video it's hard to see how anyone can answer this.

Comment: sorry, I'll put it up right away

Comment: Even with the context, I have no idea wtf he's talking about. Electrons don't have "hardness" or "color", this sounds as if he's trying to make some mangled analogy for spin in different directions, i.e. this is a weird retelling of sequential [Stern-Gerlach experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment).

Comment: Stern-gerlach experiments are exactly what this is. I hadn't heard about them, so had to come here. Thanks man